# How to set in Google Sheets an x time-efficient in all rows that contain a value according to getValues for example?

Tags: arrays, list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

In the cells of the D column there is the following formula to get the actual row number (non-hidden rows): `=if(subtotal(103,A?),row(),"")`.

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var values = s.getRange('D2:D').getValues();
  var index = 0;
  var value = values[index];
  var condition = /\S/.test(value); // printable char
  var ranges = [];
  for (values; ?; index++) {        // until the last index
    if (condition) {
      ranges.push('C'+value);
    }
  }
  s.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A [for-loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) should have 3 optional expressions: *intialization*(`var index = 0`), *condition* (`index < values.length`)and *final-expression*(`index++`).
- The variables that change(`value` and `condition`) in the loop should be inside the for-loop

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var values = s.getRange('D2:D').getValues();

  var ranges = [];
  for (var index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {        // until the last index
    var value = values[index];
    var condition = /\S/.test(value); // printable char
    if (condition) {
      ranges.push('C'+value);
    }
  }
  s.getRangeList(ranges).setValue('x');
}
```

Comment: This allows an execution time of often less than one second for 300 rows.

Comment: @user8652270 How exactly are you calculating the execution time?

Comment: At [link](https://script.google.com/home) the executions can be opened via the context menu for the respective project.